# R-ASP.NET application deployment in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, r, iis, iis-6

We have integrated R 3.1.2 with ASP.NET. But after deploying application in IIS 6.0, application is not able to call some of the R packages like RODBC, stats, etc. We are getting following error:

Error: Package or namespace load failed for stats.

The same error we are getting for package RODBC.

Comment: Have you checked your `.libPaths()`? See `?.libPaths` for details

Comment: What matters is that the R session used in the application has access to the directory where the packages are installed. The libpaths you get from an interactive R session might not reflect what's going on in your actual application.

Comment: Does it mean we may not get access R library? If yes what will be the solution ?

Comment: From R console library path is : "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.3/library" From .NET library path is : "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.3/library"

Comment: Hard to say without more info, the problem might be elsewhere... Are some other packages loaded correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your help, problem got resolved by changing IIS settings.

Comment: I am having the same issue. RODBC can not load. Can you plz explain how did you solve it?

Comment: right click on My Computer, > properties > Advanced System Setting > Environment Variables, the see in the System Variables window, there is a variable named path. Select path, click on edit and add the path where R packages have been stored.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 8.5 still same issue. thanks to "Pravin Mane"

> right click on My Computer, > properties > Advanced System Setting >
>   Environment Variables, the see in the System Variables window, there
>   is a variable named path. Select path, click on edit and add the path
>   where R packages have been stored.

One correction - enter in the path variable path to bin folder (64 or 32 bit  depends on your appool setting.) enter something like this
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\i386\
**IMPORTANT!! Restart the server, just re-starting IIS did not help me and I spent few more hours looking for solution.**